# JSP Upload file with content type "application/octet-stream"

Tags: jsp

I am working on a project which flash uploads some binary data with content type "application/octet-stream" and I need to save it in the BLOB column of the Oracle Database.

Can I use Commons fileupload?
Any sample code on this? I can just find the code for content type "multipart/form-data".

Answer (score -1):

```
private byte[] getByteArrayFromUploadFile(HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception{
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

    // Parse the request
    FileItemIterator iter = null;
    try{
        iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occured during getting iterator");
    }
    byte[] readBytes = null;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream item = null;
        try{
            item = iter.next();
         }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured during Iteration");                
        }

        String name = item.getFieldName();

        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(item.openStream());
            readBytes= new byte[stream.available()];
            System.out.println("total Number of Bytes:"+ readBytes.length);             
            stream.read(readBytes);
        }
    }
   return readBytes;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work with type “application/octet-stream”.